# Error : Group cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, groups

I deleted `Team Site Owners` group from the top level team site in SharePoint Online and found that the people and groups link from the settings page is not working, throwing an error:

> Group cannot be found.

How can this be corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can open all groups with this URL:
`{siteURL}/_layouts/15/groups.aspx`

Or you can create *Owners*, *Members*, *Visitors* groups for site:

- Go to *Site Settings* > *Site Permissions* > *Stop Inheriting Permissions*
- Rather than inheriting from parent site, create new group for site.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-create the Team site owner via the layouts page located at {yoursite}/_layouts/permsetup.aspx You can set the owners group to an existing group in this page, making it the default.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you for the reply. The next day when I reopened the Team site, the people and groups link is working fine without showing the error. Team site owners group was found under Groups list in people and groups link. I am not sure what exactly happenend. Any comments?

Comment: Not sure what the cause of that could have been. Glad to hear it is working